# How to solve template conversion to an int

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Well I have a task to make BST (Binary Search Tree) on a template. And I'm stuck on conversion problem, couse using template :/. I don't know how to get over it.  I tried this code without template and it works normally.

````
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T> struct drzewo{
    private:
        int value;
        drzewo *l ,*r;
    public:
        T NewDrzewo(int key){
            struct drzewo *temp=(struct drzewo*)malloc(sizeof(struct drzewo));
            temp->value=key;
            temp->l=temp->r=NULL;
            return temp;
        }
        void inorder(struct drzewo *root) {
            if (root != NULL) {
                inorder(root->l);
                cout << root->value << " -> ";
                inorder(root->r);
            }
        }
        T insert(struct drzewo *drzewo, int value) {
            if (drzewo == NULL) return NewDrzewo(value);
            if (value < drzewo->value){
                drzewo->l=insert(drzewo->l, value); 
            }
            else{
                drzewo->r=insert(drzewo->r, value);
            }
            return drzewo;
        }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct drzewo <int> *root = NULL;
    root->insert(root, 8);
    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Dereferencing `NULL` is a bad idea.

Comment: Please post verbatim compiler messages you are getting, and indicate relevant lines in the source.

Comment: *I'm stuck on conversion problem, couse using template* You need to actually explain what the problem is, and show the compiler error you get.

Comment: Using template supposed to mean you'll play with the types. You take `template<class T>` but still dealing with the `int value`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the template machinery incorrectly.

```
template <class T> struct drzewo{
    private:
        int value;  // THIS MAKES NO SENSE
```

The idea of the template is to pass thet type of the stored element as a parameter and not to hard code it. Thus you should be using

```
        T value;
```

instead of

```
        int value;
```

Since `T` is the type of your stored element and not the type of your tree,

```
T NewDrzewo(int key){
```

is also wrong, you should be using

```
drzewo* NewDrzewo(T key){
```

Likewise, `T insert(... int value)` should be `drzewo* insert(... T value)`.

There are other issues unrelated to this one, for example (in no particular order):

1. Using `malloc`. Don't do that, use `new` instead.
2. Not using constructors and destructors.
3. Using elaborate-type-specifiers (`struct drzewo`) without any reason. Use `drzewo` instead.
4. Using the obsolete `NULL` macro. Use `nullptr` instead.
5. `using namespace std` is dangerous, never do that.
6. `insert` and `NewDrzewo` should be static functions as they do not use `this`. `root->insert(root, 8)` should be `root = drzewo<int>::insert(root, 0)` because `root->` is illegal when `root` is a null pointer.